# The most proper place to set systemwide shell alias in a Linux system

Tags: linux, bash, bashrc, .bash-profile, bash-alias

There are many places to set an alias for all users within a Linux system,
e.g. `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`...

I'm wondering which one is the most proper/correct, in other words, which one is the best in accordance to the conventions of Linux nowadays.

Sorry for my English, I hope I have expressed myself well.

Comment: It depends on whether your shell is Interactive login, Interactive non-login or Script. See [Zsh/Bash startup files loading order (.bashrc, .zshrc etc.) | The Lumber Room](https://shreevatsa.wordpress.com/2008/03/30/zshbash-startup-files-loading-order-bashrc-zshrc-etc/)

Comment: Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. I mean please [make sure you know you want an alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618). If the real question is "how can I add a custom command recognized system-wide?" or "how can I modify the behavior of `something`, so it always uses `--some-option`, system-wide?" then an alias is not necessarily the best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of placing the aliases depend on when you want to be able to use them.

Bash uses the following start-up files:

```
                    Login shell              Non-login shell
----------------------------------------------------------------
Interactive shell   /etc/profile             /etc/bash.bashrc
                    ~/.bash_profile          ~/.bashrc
                    ~/.bash_login
                    ~/.profile
```

`/etc/profile` sources `/etc/bash.bashrc` and the files `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`

So, if you want to use them in a login-shell only (typically if you login via `ssh`), place them in `/etc/profile.d`. If you want to use them in a non-login shell (`xterm`, `konsole` etc.) too, place them in `/etc/bash.bashrc`.